# symfony2 upload file with a form

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony

i have managed to create a form with a file upload select button.
Thing is i dunno how to proceed next to save and retrieve this upload file?

my entity look like this

```
 /**
 * @var File $file       
 * 
 */    
private $file;  


/**
 * Set file

 * @param Fichier $file 
 */
public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file
 * @return fichier
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}
```

my form contains

```
    $builder   

           ->add("file", "file")
    ;
}
```

so far so good but when i click create , dunno what happen to my file

my controller contains :

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new Candidat();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CandidatType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        #foreach($entity->getFile() as $file)
        #                      {
        #                        $file->upload();
        #                  }


        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('candidat_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: All is explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: is there nothing more simple ? i dont understand how to fit that uploadAction in my createAction?

Comment: attempt with cookbook above ... An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Document (name, path) VALUES (?, ?)' with params {"1":"test","2":null} !?